# Tasting typical Czech cuisine in Prague

Tags: food-and-drink, restaurants, czech-republic, local-cuisine

I'll be going to Prague in a few weeks. As usual for my job travels I'm trying also to enjoy the place, and in this case the cuisine.

I tried to have a look on Wikipedia [Czech Cuisine page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Czech_cuisine), and it makes a nice list of local food. In my understanding the very, very MUST TASTE food are the knedlíky (dumplings), some soups, and the famous Guláš.

So my question is:

- Is there any other typical-Czech-dinner food? Is there any list of such national dishes?

Comment: Many would argue that beer is an important part of Czech cuisine too! How important would it be to you that the place you go for dinner also does good+interesting+local beer too?

Comment: uh, right... I didn't take it into account... beer is of course important:)

Comment: disagree with on hold, as there are typical foods and goods for Czech Republic, but agree with on hold about places, where to enjoy. This could be an opinion. Please change wording of the question this way.

Comment: @Dee Thanks for your comment, I modified the question accordingly-

Comment: I don't think questions like this have any kind of concise objective answer other than something like pointing to the Wikipedia article, which you already found. This is backed up by the current and natural form of the question, "do you think ..." - this is asking for recommendations and that's something we only do in very narrow cases. For instance if you had tried and failed to find a certain typical dish.

Comment: I think that both places and dishes could in principle be OK but the question is very broad (see e.g. http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/23462/wild-game-for-lunch-or-dinner-in-northern-virginia-usa for one that was accepted). I didn't vote either way but following the various discussions, I don't think that focusing only on dishes would be enough to keep this question open.